# Creating an array of objects in PHP with for loop

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I am trying to get data from mysql data, create objects from it. Here I have written some code. I am getting thing's details from a database. Now for each result I want an object to be created which is finally merged with an array output. This `$output` array is finally outputted as json.

I am getting error :

`array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array`

How to create arrays of objects in PHP ?

```
public function getDetails()    //This is a class function
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `thing` WHERE `id` = :thingId";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare ( $query );
    $stmt->bindParam ( ":thingId" , $_GET['thingId']  );
    $stmt->execute ( );
    $rslt  =  $stmt->fetch ( );
    $thingName  = $rslt['name'];
    $thingOwnerId = $rslt['userId'];
    $thingDescription = $rslt['thingDescription'];

    // Getting the thing owner details
    $query = "SELECT * from `user` WHERE ( `id` = :id ) ";    
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->bindParam ( ":id" , $thingOwnerId );
    $stmt->execute(  );
    $rslt = $stmt->fetch ( );
    $thingOwnerName = $rslt['firstName']." ".$rslt['lastName'];
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM `things` ; ";
$s = $dbh->prepare($query);
$s->execute();
$r = $s->fetchAll();
foreach($r as $r1)
{
    $newThing = new Thingy($r1['id']);
    $newThing->getDetails();
    $output =  array_merge($output,$newThing);
}

$output2 = json_encode($output);
header('content-type: application/json');
echo $output2;
```

Comment: And where you've defined your parameter#2 i.e. `$newRoute` ?

Comment: You have not defined variable $newRoute so it value is undefined and array_merge requires arguments as array so php fires error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
$output = [];
foreach($r as $r1)
{
    $newThing = new Thingy($r1['id']);
    $newThing->getDetails();
    $output[] = $newThing;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could save yourself some work here and use `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` as the `$fetch_style`. Basically it allows you to specify a custom class, the properties of which you can populate with matching return values from each row in your query. Note the first argument in the method signature:

> public array PDOStatement::fetchAll ([ int $fetch_style [, mixed $fetch_argument [, array $ctor_args = array() ]]] )

As illustrated in example #4 from the `PDOStatement::fetchAll()` [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

```
<?php
class fruit {
    public $name;
    public $colour;
}

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, "fruit");
var_dump($result);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks ! Thats really helpful ! But I am getting data from multiple tables. And creating a single object out of it. Will it work in that case ?

Comment: Yes it should be completely fine, all you need is an object with the same properties as the columns you are returning from your database - this can be from one or many tables - you are mapping the returned data to the object, so PHP does not care about the underlying table structure. It's a pretty useful feature imho!

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple things that could potentially be causing problems.

First, and likely the cause of your issues, is that `array_merge` only accepts arguments of type `array`. [See the documentation](https://www.php.net/array_merge). However, you can either cast the type of `$newThing` to be an array, or more succinctly just do a manual append [as suggested in this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19859438/13604).

Second, your method `getDetails()` neither returns anything, nor does is it a class method that modifies an object's contents. It needs to be one or the other; right now it runs and the results aren't permanently stored anywhere. Since you've indicated it's a class method, then it should look like this:

```
public function getDetails()    //This is a class function
{
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `thing` WHERE `id` = :thingId";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare ( $query );
    $stmt->bindParam ( ":thingId" , $_GET['thingId']  );
    $stmt->execute ( );
    $rslt  =  $stmt->fetch ( );
    $this->thingName  = $rslt['name'];                    // Class variable
    $this->thingOwnerId = $rslt['userId'];                // Class variable
    $this->thingDescription = $rslt['thingDescription'];  // Class variable

    // Getting the thing owner details
    $query = "SELECT * from `user` WHERE ( `id` = :id ) ";    
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare( $query );
    $stmt->bindParam ( ":id" , $thingOwnerId );
    $stmt->execute(  );
    $rslt = $stmt->fetch ( );
    $this->thingOwnerName = $rslt['firstName']." ".$rslt['lastName']; // Class variable
}
```

Comment: Updated my question. `$newRoute` isn't the problem. Also, the `getDetails()` doesn't returns anything but it does defines many attributes of the object created.

Comment: It's not a class method, so it's not modifying any attributes either. Unless you omitted the class definitions and use of `$this->` before posting your code?